# Ionic 5, Angular 9 application not getting loaded in Prod build. But works on Ionic serve. No error on console

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular9, ionic5

I have recently migrated the app from ionic 4 to 5 - Angular 7 to 9.
Made all the migration specific changes to config & code. Ionic serve works well.
Also no error while creating a production build. But app is not getting loaded!
Also used service worker in application.

followed the migration guidelines provided by Ionic & Angular

Package.json -->

```
 {   "name": "OpsTrakker",   "version": "1.3.1",   "author": "Ionic Framework",   "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",   "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --stats-json --build-optimizer=true --vendor-chunk=true --aot --baseHref=/OpsTrakkerWeb/",
    "buildIonic": "ionic build --prod --release -- --base-href /OpsTrakkerWeb/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"   },   "private": true,   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^5.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.26.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.25.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^7.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^7.0.0-beta.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^16.0.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^21.2.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^21.2.1",
    "angular-split": "^3.0.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^2.0.9",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-cookie-sync": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "help": "3.0.2",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.6",
    "ionic-selectable": "4.5.2",
    "ionic4-auto-complete": "2.5.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "ng-block-ui": "^2.1.8",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime-moment": "^1.0.8",
    "ngx-pinch-zoom": "^1.2.5",
    "ngx-webcam": "^0.2.6",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"   },   "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.13.8",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.5.1",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.12",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.16.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0"   },   "description": "An Ionic project",   "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-cookie-sync": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "browser",
      "ios"
    ],
    "config": {
      "ionic_uglifyjs": "./config/uglifyjs.config.js"
    }   } }
```

Comment: Do you have any log?

Comment: no console log getting printed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of analysis, I got this resolved by making **buildOptimizer** flag as false.

Make sure in angular.json setting -->

```
"buildOptimizer": false
```